# How do I create composite key using loopback4?

Tags: loopbackjs

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    uid int NOT NULL,
    username nvarchar(65) NULL,
    password varchar(100) NULL,
    firstname nvarchar(50) NULL,
    lastname nvarchar(50) NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY (id, uid);
```

This is my sql query and want to create data model for this schema using loopback4.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that this feature is currently supported. An open issue tracking this feature can be found on their GitHub page [here.](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1830)